# how to retrieve multiple data from database using SqlDataReader?

Tags: asp.net

i have database table in which i have two columns name picid and pic1..in my pic1 column i have three data..now while wanting to retrive the data using sqldatareader i am getting the top of the column data..how to get the all data of that column and use it for the further purpose..

my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string con = " ";
    con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);
    objsqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From pictable", objsqlconn);
    SqlDataReader grpIDreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    grpIDreader.Read();
    string path = grpIDreader["pic1"].ToString();
    //slide.Attributes["style"] = String.Format("background-image:url('{0}')", path);
    image1.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("{0}", path);
    image2.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("{1}", path);
    image3.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("{2}", path);
}
```

i want to just get the path which are saved in the pic1 column of the database..
i am getting this error " System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."
i have tried like that also and getting same error

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string con = " ";
    con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);
    objsqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From pictable", objsqlconn);
    SqlDataReader grpIDreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    string[] path={"","",""};
    int i = 0;
    while(grpIDreader.Read())
    {
         path[i++] = grpIDreader["pic1"].ToString();

    }


    //slide.Attributes["style"] = String.Format("background-image:url('{0}')", path);
    image1.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("{0}", path[0]);
    image2.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("{1}", path[1]);
    image3.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("{2}", path[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a string formatting error, not a database error:

```
image1.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("{0}", path); //This works, as 0 indicates the first argument you are passing in
image2.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("{1}", path); //This won't work, as you are asking for the second argument, which doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to get each row

```
using (SqlDataReader grpIDreader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
 while (grpIDreader.Read()) //.Read() advances to the next row and returns false if there are no more
{
string path = grpIDreader["pic1"].ToString();
//other stuff here
}
}
```

also

instead of this

```
image1.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("{0}", path[0]);
```

do this

```
image1.Attributes["src"] = path[0];
```